# Compare two excel cells and then eventually send an email from Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a Python program that tracks prices of products, and updates the info onto an Excel sheet. I am scraping the productName and productPrice from Amazon & Chem Warehouse and then writing it on to an Excel sheet.

Here is what my Excel data looks like:

```
Date    Time    Item    Cost

October 16, 2022    02:26:50    Versace Man Eau Fraiche Eau de Toilette for Men, 100ml  69.99

October 16, 2022    02:26:54    Versace Man Eau Fraiche Eau de Toilette for Men, 100ml  69.99

October 16, 2022    15:33:55    Versace Man Eau Fraiche Eau de Toilette for Men, 100ml  69.99

October 16, 2022    15:33:55    Burberry London Fabric Eau De Parfum, 100ml 59

October 16, 2022    15:54:55    Versace Man Eau Fraiche Eau de Toilette for Men, 100ml  69.99   
October 16, 2022    15:54:55    Burberry London Fabric Eau De Parfum, 100ml 59  
October 16, 2022    16:10:40    Versace Man Eau Fraiche Eau de Toilette for Men, 100ml  69.99   
October 16, 2022    16:10:40    Burberry London Fabric Eau De Parfum, 100ml 59
```

Now, I want to compare the price of each corresponding product, and then send an email to myself with any price changes. I'm having a hard time understanding the logic behind how to compare two cells in Excel, and then send an email to myself (this part I can figure out, just need some help with the logic behind comparing two cells).

Here's my Python code: https://pastecode.io/s/mxqdci37

Answer (score 0):

You need to `merge` the two dataframes and leave the rows where the price is different:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='Item', how='left')
df1 = df1[df1['Cost_x'] != df1['Cost_y']]
```

The resulting `df1` will have only the rows with the changed prices